# Another footer that won't stay at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I know this has been asked several times before and I am going crazy trying to resolve the issue for something that I know I am just overlooking.

My footer isn't being placed at the bottom of the page where content doesn't extend past the need to scroll. Any page with limited content the footer has a large margin below the footer div and the actual bottom of page.

I have my current html as

```
<footer class="site-footer">
    <div class="page-wrapper">
    </div>
</footer>
```

and my css as

```
.site-footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10em auto 0;
  background: white;
  padding: 1.5em;
  height: 90px;
  margin-bottom: -90px;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It stays at the bottom right?

Comment: what is your isseue? I see it at bottom of the page...

Comment: @ManojKumar I just updated the issue description some. A good example of the issue is the contact page. Thank you

Comment: If you are not aware what `position: relative` accomplishes – and more importantly, what _not_ – then I suggest you go read up on it.

Comment: It seems to be working ok for me. Th contact page footer looks ok too. What is your issue exactly??

Comment: Okay i understood what kind of problem @EricH is facing.

Comment: you might want to stop trying out every answer directly onto the main project and publishing it, it's making the fix difficult

Answer (score 0):

Set `padding-bottom: 0` to `.page` and replace `position: relative` with `position: absolute`

```
.page {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.site-footer {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: using `overflow: hidden` on the body removes the ability to scroll for content

Comment: I chose the wrong class and have edited it. There was a padding-bottom for .page. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The footer is not at the bottom because of the position: relative which is just resting it at the bottom of the pages content.

To have it stay at the bottom of each and every page I'd suggest:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
height: 90px;
```

etc..

You may review a demo at [How to Keep the Footer Down](http://cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/ss/)%20for%20a%20demo)

Answer (score 0):

The only gap I see is when the page is in a certain width (less than 680px screen width) and that is caused by this property:

```
.page-column {
  text-align: left !important;
  display: block !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 2em auto;
}
```

Remove the `margin: 2em;` and the gap will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `position: fixed`:

```
.site-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 90px;
}
```

This affixes the footer div to the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: The `position: fixed` works properly, I actually had been using the fixed position before but was looking to change it out - which is where I am running into the issue.

Comment: If you want the footer to stay attached to the bottom of the window, then `position: fixed` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest fix.

Just add this to your CSS.

```
body {
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

there's nothing actually wrong with your CSS, it's just that somewhere you have given some padding to your body element causing the issue.

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]